# how to delete duplicates from hive table by creating new hive table with same structure with the existing table?

Tags: hadoop

1)create one dummy table with one column
2)load the data from main tabl to dummy table
3)Do the overwrite into the dummy table by selecting the one field 
4)load back this dummytable data to main table by using insert overwriteinto table

How to do this process? While I am trying to load the data from main table to dummy table it can't processed.  Justify the answer. pls!

hive> load data local inpath '/user/hive/warehouse/keyrun.db/rama/mous' into table seetha;
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''/user/hive/warehouse/keyrun.db/rama/mous'': No files matching path file:/user/hive/warehouse/keyrun.db/rama/mous
hive>

I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

create table dummy as select column from main_table;